# Асинхронная работа с диском с помощью Linux AIO. В чем заключается асинхронность?

Tags: linux, c, файловая-система, асинхронность

Почитал про linux AIO, не понимаю в чем заключается асинхронность. Мы же не можешь читать с диска в память в фоновом режиме, нам все равно нужен поток/процесс который будет производить операцию чтения из диска в память. Или AIO использует какую то невиданную мне магию? Прочитал статью где Linux AIO сравнивают с POSIX AIO и говорят, что 2 вариант использует дополнительные потоки а первый нет, как это возможно?

Еще один вопрос, возможно ли подружить данное api с еполом и отслеживать окончание чтение через него, я знаю что сам AIO предоставляет свой мультиплексор, но это крайне не популярное решение.

Comment: aio уже не модно. Модно [IO_URING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_uring)

Comment: По второму вопросу - [да, можно использовать epoll для отслеживания событий AIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825621/how-do-you-use-aio-and-epoll-together-in-a-single-event-loop)

Comment: По крайней мере с середины 80-х (bsd 4.2) в *nix существуют неблокируемые дескрипторы (см. [man fcntl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) O_ASYNC, SIGIO (imho select/poll/epoll обеспечивают более удобный механизм, чем обработка сигнала)), как раз обеспечивающие низкоуровневый интерфейс к  асинхронному вводу-выводу. Т.е. сделали read,  потом можем что-то вычислять и смотреть, когда данные реально будут скопированы в буфер user space.

Comment: @avp - вот чтобы не копировать туды-сюды, в ядра Линукса, начиная с 5.1, завезли IO_URING

Comment: @gbg, к сожалению с IO_URING не знаком, подозреваю, что у него общие корни с mmap

Comment: @avp, разве если мы делаем дескриптор неблокирующим, при вызове рид мы все равно не должны ждать пока данные скопируются в буфер? По идее при таком раскладе read просто возвращает -1 если чтение по каким то причинам не доступно

Comment: @DenverToha, насколько помню, read возвращает -1, а errno устанавливается в EAGAIN. После получения сигнала надо снова вызвать read. (Впрочем, в linux с regular files (обычными файлами на диске) я это никогда не пробовал, подозреваю, что не взирая на O_ASYNC/O_NONBLOCK read будет работать как обычно (синхронно), поскольку все равно для таких файлов по умолчанию в ядре реализовано опережающее чтение и ранее уже прочитанные данные копируются в user space)

Comment: @DenverToha, вот попалась [Asynchronous I/O on linux
or: Welcome to hell.](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~piyush/teach/4531_06/project/hell.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мы же не можешь читать с диска в память в фоновом режиме, нам все равно нужен поток/процесс который будет производить операцию чтения из диска в память.

Как раз смысл асинхронного IO в том, что устройство само, без участия ЦП, пишет или читает память. Это называется direct memory access, DMA. Именно это происходить в при overlapped io в Windows. На linux же API Linux AIO обычно по разным причинам не работоспособно, а POSIX AIO предоставляет асинхронное апи выполняя обычное чтение и запись в фоном потоке. Так же что используйте неблокирующий ввод.